# Most secure remote access to home computer/network

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I am looking for an very secure option to access my home computer remotely.

I am considering a DD-WRT router with OpenVPN and then once VPN'ed into the network, use Remote Desktop to access my machine (and any other network resources).

I was considering also using a white list of IP's (which would only be my Verizon Mi-Fi) but I don't really want to pay $500 for a static IP address.

Someone else mentioned port knocking.  Can that be used in conjunction with VPN and, if so, would that hide the VPN surface from would be intruders until the port knock sequence was performed?

I should add that I will only be accessing this from my personal laptop so I don't mind being limited as far as password complexity or client certificates.  Any other options for the most secure was of doing this would be appreciated!

Comment: use a cert installed on your machine to access the VPN (DD-WRT supports that) - that should be sufficient

Comment: Off topic, but a static IP is $500?! That seems insane.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @schroeder in his comment, the state of the art way if to use a x509 certificate to authenticate yourself on the VPN. Depending on your security requirements, you can go from a passwordless user certificate in the laptop cert store (easy to use but broken if laptop is stolen), a password protected certificate on the laptop (attacker will need both the cert private key and its password) or a certificate on a smartcard (true 2FA with something you have - the smartcard - and something you know - the cert password).

It is certainly possible to imagine other ways, but I strongly advise you not to roll your own for security questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having authorization software on your device restricting only your device connecting remote.

DD-WRT router with VPN is a strong start and is probably more than enough for your average protection when it comes to security threats.

Not an expert in port knocking, but as far as I can see, there is no reason why it wouldn't work with a VPN.

Additionally, you could investigate IPsec VPN approaches with certifications.